# C++ if() into switch and case statement

Tags: c++

I have if() function for ternary operator (':', '?')

```
if(operation == ':')
....
....
   if(operation == '?')
....
   return new ternaryOperator(first, second, third)
```

These give a perfect operation value. But I need to make them 
Switch() and Case statement. I have used Switch() and nested Switch() statement as well, but it doesn't return correct value.
How do I put those if functions into Switch and Case statement ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "expression.h"
#include "subexpression.h"
#include "operand.h"
#include "plus.h"
#include "minus.h"
#include "times.h"
#include "divide.h"
#include "greaterThan.h"
#include "lessThan.h"
#include "equal.h"
#include "and.h"
#include "or.h"
#include "notEqual.h"
#include "ternaryOperator.h"

SubExpression::SubExpression(Expression* left, Expression* right){
   this->left = left;
   this->right = right;
}

SubExpression::SubExpression(Expression* first, Expression* second, Expression* third)
{
   this->first = first;
   this->second = second;
   this->third = third;
}

SubExpression::SubExpression(Expression* left)
{
   this->left = left;
}

Expression* SubExpression::parse()
{
   Expression* left;
   Expression* right;
   Expression* first;
   Expression* second;
   Expression* third;
   char operation, paren;
   bool isTernary = false;

   left = Operand::parse();
   cin >> operation;
   right = Operand::parse();

   **if (operation == ':')
   {
      first = left;
      second = right;
      left = Operand::parse();
      cin >> operation;
      right = Operand::parse();
      if (operation == '?')
      {
         third = right;
         isTernary = true;
      }
   }

   cin >> paren;

   if (isTernary == true)
   {
      return new ternaryOperator(first, second, third);
   }**

   switch (operation)
   {

      case '+':
         return new Plus(left, right);
      case '-':
         return new Minus(left, right);
      case '*':
         return new Times(left, right);
      case '/':
         return new Divide(left, right);
      case '>':
         return new greaterThan(left, right);
      case '<':
         return new lessThan(left, right);
      case '=':
         return new Equal(left, right);
      case '&':
         return new And(left, right);
      case '|':
         return new Or(left, right);

      case '!':
         return new notEqual(left);
   }
   return 0;
}



class ternaryOperator: public SubExpression
{
   public:
      ternaryOperator(Expression* first, Expression* second, Expression* third):
            SubExpression(first, second, third)
   {
   }
      double evaluate()
      {
         return third->evaluate() ? first->evaluate() : second->evaluate();
      }
};
```

Comment: `switch()` can't handle string literals.

Comment: But it can handle character literals (note the single quote, not double). @JC315, can you show your attempt at the switch statements for those 'operation' values?

Comment: case ':'
                first = left;
                second = right;
            switch(operation){
                case'?':
                    third = right;
                    isTernary = true;
            }
                if (isTernary == true)
 {
  return new ternaryOperator(first, second, third);
 }

Comment: Thank for your response.

Comment: Off topic: Lot of pointers flying around. Remember that someone has to clean all that up at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I was able to break the nested if(operation == '?') into the below Switch and case statements and it worked.
But I still need put the main if(operation ==':') into switch and case statements

```
if (operation == ':')
    {
        first = left;
        second = right;
        left = Operand::parse();
        cin >> operation;
        right = Operand::parse();}
..
...
....
case '?':
    third = right;
    return new ternaryOperator(first, second, third);
```